# Slice an array and make mutidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I need to slice and array using a `for loop` and the `slice()` and `push()` methods.

I tried every possible way (except the right one obviously) but no way to figure out the solution.

Please to explain because I am always in trouble when it comes to recursion and for loops.

```
 function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  // Break it up.
  var finalArray = [];

  // var firsPart = arr.slice(0, 2);
  // var secondPart = arr.slice(2, 4);
  // console.log(firsPart);
  // console.log(secondPart);

  // finalArray.push(firsPart, secondPart);

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var slicingIndex = 0;
    var sliced = arr.slice(size);

    finalArray.push(sliced);
    }

  return finalArray;
}

console.log(chunkArrayInGroups(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2));
console.log(chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3));
console.log(chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2));
console.log(chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 4));
console.log(chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 3));
console.log(chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 4));
console.log(chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 2));
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a while loop and slice with the index and the updated index with the wanted length.

```js
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
    var finalArray = [],
        i = 0;

    while (i < arr.length) {
        finalArray.push(arr.slice(i, i += size));
    }
    return finalArray;
}

console.log(chunkArrayInGroups(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2));
console.log(chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3));
console.log(chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2));
console.log(chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 4));
console.log(chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 3));
console.log(chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 4));
console.log(chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

By no means an expert, but I think this might help.

```
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  var finalArray = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (finalArray.length !== size) {
      var sliced = arr.slice(i);
      finalArray.push(sliced);
    }
  }

  return finalArray;
}

console.log(chunkArrayInGroups(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2));
console.log(chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3));
console.log(chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2));
console.log(chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 4));
console.log(chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 3));
console.log(chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 4));
console.log(chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 2));
```